# Is it possible to use Azure Automation Runbook to delete another Runbook output (an Azure File share snapshot)?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, fileshare, runbook

I want to use the runbook to delete another runbook output (an Azure File Share snapshot).

Is it possible? If you know something, please write something at here

Runbook 1: Create an Azure File share snapshot

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey 
$share = Get-AzureStorageShare -Context 
$context -Name "sharefile" 
$snapshot = $share.Snapshot()
```

Runbook 2: Delete the Azure runbook output. The problem with this is that it deletes all snapshots rather than just delete the one created by the first runbook.

```
$allsnapshots = Get-AzureStorageShare -Context $context | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "sharefile" -and $_.IsSnapshot -eq $true } 
foreach($snapshot in $allsnapshots){ 
    if($snapshot.SnapshotTime -lt (get-date).Add·Hours()){ 
        $snapshot.Delete()
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185480/discussion-on-question-by-arthur-is-it-possible-to-use-azure-automation-runbook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample code is as below, I test it in runbook and works well(create a snapshot, and then delete it after 3 minutes), and **the other snapshots have no effect**.

code in my powershell runbook:

```
param(
[string]$username,
[string]$password,
[string]$filesharename
)

$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $username -StorageAccountKey $password
$share = Get-AzureStorageShare -Context $context -Name $filesharename
$s = $share.snapshot()

#get the snapshot name, which is always a UTC time formated value
$s2= $s.SnapshotQualifiedStorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString()

#the $snapshottime is actually equal to snapshot name
$snapshottime = $s2.Substring($s2.IndexOf('=')+1)
write-output "create a snapshot"
write-output $snapshottime

#wait 180 seconds, then delete the snapshot 
start-sleep -s 180

write-output "delete the snapshot"
$snap = Get-AzureStorageShare -Context $context -SnapshotTime $snapshottime -Name $filesharename 
$snap.Delete()

write-output "deleted successfully after 3 minutes"
```

**after it's running, you can see the snapshot is created in azure portal:**

[image]

**After it completes, the specified snapshot is deleted(you may need to open a new webpage to see the change due to some cache issue)**

**the output in runbook:**

[image]

Comment: I will have a try, thanks so much. Later I will edit the question and mark it as an answer.

Comment: I tested it and it works very well. There have something I want to check with you. 1: Should I have to use the "param", just now I tried to create a snapshot last time you told me (*Runbook1 code), but there has errored out, I will test it again later. 2: Will the job keep running until the snapshot be deleted?  If it's true, may I use it with the  Schedules to achieve the goal " Create a snapshot every day and delete it after one week"?   If you know something, please let me know, I will test it with some schedules, thanks, Ivan.

Comment: 1. not necessary to use param 2.yes, it keeps running until the snapshot being deleted. it may not be able achieve your goal. The only solution I can figure out is that use another runbook which uses to delete the snapshots created a week ago.

Comment: The solution you said is deleting all the snapshots created a week ago or just delete some of them? Is it possible to use another Runbook to connect with the Create Runbook to achieve the goal?                                  
Now I am testing the runbook upside with schedules (Create once an hour and delete it after two hours), I will tell you the result later, I hope it can work, God.  Thanks so much, Ivan.

Comment: I think we can have the control to delete all of them a week ago or some of them a week ago. for "use another Runbook to connect with the Create Runbook to achieve the goal", it's really hard I think:(

Comment: Can you tell me how to control to delete "some of them" a week ago? 
    '#wait 180 seconds, then delete the snapshot 
    start-sleep -s 180'                                                                                                 
  I have a question about the time: can we use "days, weeks, months or years".      
  thanks

Comment: for 1: we can loop all the snapshots, and get their created time, then you can set a time range(like > 7 days and < 8 days), if the snapshots are in this time range will be deleted.  For 2, if use start-sleep, only supports seconds or Milliseconds, we need to convert, not very difficult, just use code like this, e.g. 7 days: `start-sleep -s $(60*60*24*7)` :)

Comment: I want to inform u the runbook can be running well. Just now I run two Runbooks to create the same file share snapshots with schedules (1, I set create once an hour and delete after two hours 2, I set another one to create every two hours and delete after 3hour). Now the first one had finished the delete work without effects to other snapshots, the test also keeps running, if there have some errors I will let you know. Also your another solution is sound interesting, I want to have a try.  Thanks again, Ivan.

Comment: You're welcome, if possible, could you please mark it as an answer? thank you:)

Comment: Hi, Ivan, I tested the runbooks yesterday and I found some error this morning. I created three runbooks with the different set of delete time, but just the first one can go well. The others can create snapshot well but can't delete. (Their job statues show stopped and the explanation is as below), do you know why? Thanks. Exception: 
The job was evicted and subsequently reached a Stopped state. The job cannot continue running.

Comment: Hi @Arthur Arthur, I've just found something about the limitation, in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution#fair-share), it mentions that **In order to share resources among all runbooks in the cloud, Azure Automation will temporarily unload or stop any job that has been running for more than three hours**.

Comment: but it will run again when the schedules work, but its status will become stopped soon, it's mean it can create snapshots but can't delete them. Can you tell me the code about the solution that "we can loop all the snapshots, and get their created time, then you can set a time range(like > 7 days and < 8 days), if the snapshots are in this time range will be deleted"? I want to have a test about that, thanks

Comment: Hi @Arthur, could you please open a new question for it? thanks.

Comment: if you're done, please let me know, I can post it :)

Comment: Hi @Ivan Yang,  I met an error when I create the Azure file share's snapshots,  Exception calling "Snapshot" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict."
 At line:3 char:1
 + $snapshot = $share.Snapshot()
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException
 I had open another question, could you please check it? Thanks so much.